# C# LINQ to DATASET Grouping with a total

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

I have a datatable in a data set.  The table has 3 columns and it is not grouped.

```
 Table1
 Field1  string
 Field2  datetime
 Field3  decimal
```

I need it grouped on Field1, Field2, with it totaled on Field3

Tring to accomplish this in LINQ but results are not coming out correctly.

I want to do this back into the original data table in the dataset (in the foreach?) but if that is not possible I know it is easy to remove/add the table.

Here is what I have so far but it is not quite working;

```
  var newSort = from row in objectTable.AsEnumerable()
        group row by new { 
               fullname = row.Field<string>("fullname"),
               attenddate = row.Field<DateTime>("attenddate"), 
        } into grp
        select new
             {
             fullname = grp.Key.fullname,
             attenddate = grp.Key.attenddate,
             Sumdayshours = grp.Sum(r => r.Field<Double>("dayshours"))
              };

  foreach (var row in newSort)
        {
            dsTemp.Tables["GroupedData"].Rows.Add(fullname, row.attenddate, row.Sumdayshours);
        }
```

Comment: It's `...Rows.Add(row.fullname...` instead of `Rows.Add(fullname`. Typo? Since the code looks fine(apart from that), how are _results are not coming out correctly_? Can you show sample data?

Comment: I found it.  Notice in the foreach the fullname variable is not prefaced with row.  Thus that column was wrongly populated.  Sometimes it helps to stop staring at the code and sleep on it.  Tim helped to, thanks for the verification.  Also if there is a way to group a table in a dataset without creating a second table I would like to know.  For now this will work.  Thanks